# Removing html Entities from string to fix Unexpected token in JSON ERROR

Tags: javascript, json, regex, angular, html-entities

how do I remove all the "\n" and spaces and things like "&nbsp":

I tried this but it didn't do the trick: `x.replace(/\\/g, '').replace('&nbsp;', '').replace('\n', '');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regex

```
console.log( x.replace(/(&nbsp;|<([^>]+)>)/ig, "") );
```

```js
 var x = `{    \n    \"formType\":\"CreateCaseRequest\",\n    \"documentID\":270550224,\n    \"documentRev\":\"1\",\n    \"formVersion\":\"v1\",\n    \"createdDateTime\":\"2019-03-25T13:31:44.216+0000\",\n    \"documentStatus\":\"Draft\",\n    \"documentTitle\":\n    {\n    },\n    \"documentSynopsis\":\n    {\n    },\n    \"highPriority\":false,\n   }`

console.log( x.replace(/(&nbsp;|<([^>]+)>)/ig, "") );
```

Comment: Thanks can you explain what that means: `(&nbsp;|<([^>]+)>)/ig, ""` is that saying replace all htmle entities with `""` or just the `\n`

Comment: Yes, all HTML entities

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

x.replace("\n", "\n");

Comment: Thanks this worked but what about to remove another entities like &nbsp etc